# Using two voltage regulators (780x) in series to prevent heat sink

Tags: voltage-regulator, 7805

(updated due to remark of ChrisStratton).

I am wondering if it is a good idea to use two regulators in series.

What I want: using 2 12V Nema17 motors (using 12V, 1.7A each).
Using a microcontroller board (STM32F103C8T6 in most cases, 5V input voltage). However, I'm not sure what to add (except DMX possibly also a nRF24L01+ 2.4 GHz transceiver), multiple LEDs (5 mA each). So assume I need max. 200 mA.

Than my power dissipation if I would use a single 7805 would be (12 V - 5 V) * 0.2 A = 1.4 W

I heard above 0.8 or 0.9 W a heatsink is adviced. However, what if I use two regulators in series:

- 7809: power dissipation: (12 V - 9 V) * 0.2 A = 0.6 W
- 7805: power dissipation (  9 V - 5 V) * 0.2 A = 0.8 W

Would this work? And if so, should I place them with some distance not to heat each other?

Comment: There is also the possibility to use a buck

Comment: How are the LEDs arranged? Can you put a bunch in series so that you can connect the groups to the 12 V rail instead of dropping the voltage?

Comment: I second PlasmaHH. When you run into this type of problem with a linear voltage regulator, it usually means that the linear regulator is the wrong tool for the job. Use a buck regulator instead.

Comment: Sometimes you can use a series resistor or a shunt resistor in lieu of the 2nd regulator, depending on the min/max current drawn by the load.

Comment: One time I have solved this kind of problem simply by using some diodes instead of the first regulator. One must take care of the tension varations with temperature, diode fab specifications etc... of course

Comment: @PlasmaHH I try to avoid a buck converter, mostly because my knowledge of electronics is not that high, also since they occupy quite some space.

Comment: @loudnoises The leds are notification leds so I cannot put them in series, however, nothing stops me from getting the voltage from 12V (and using a higher value resistor).

Comment: @glen_geek Thanks, I heard about shunt resistors, but not sure what they do, so I need to check into this.

Comment: @andre I need to check if this is a possibility. I got the solution for a small lowering of voltage. However, from 12 to 5 V is a bit much, unless I use a lot of diodes.

Comment: yes, i do that all the time to get to 3.3v from beefy transformers and it works well.

Comment: You could consider using one of [these](https://www.digikey.com/products/en/power-supplies-board-mount/dc-dc-converters/922?k=&pkeyword=&pv16=7272&FV=17d4003e%2C1f140000%2Cii1%7C2211%2Cffe0039a%2C1140050&quantity=0&ColumnSort=0&page=1&pageSize=25). Same pinout and almost the same footprint of a linear 7805, but is a DC-DC converter.

Comment: Not wanting to learn about new things is a bad reason to not use things. There are modules about the size of a to220 available if you don't want discrete products.

Comment: The STM32 does not take 5v input, so something is wrong with your question statement.  Are you making the mistake of conflating a microcontroller *board* with a microcontroller?  Also beware that running 12v steppers on only 12 volts will be disappointing - you typically want several times the ohmic coil voltage into a chopper driver (realistically, you want lower impedance motors).

Comment: @brhans I don't see the added value, or are those more efficient?

Comment: @dandavis I think you also made the remark about diodes in my previous question (thanks for that). Thought it would be not a good idea for 12 V to 5 V

Comment: @PlasmaHH It's not that I don't want to learn (to be honest, since I'm on this forum and started electronics, I don't do anything else). But I read that buck converters was better to avoid by newcomers.

Comment: @ChrisStratton I indeed mean a microcontroller board (STM32F103C8T6 blue pill in most cases). I am a bit unsure about your next remark? You mean I need more than 12V? I also would need to check what ohmic coil voltage means, what a chopper driver is, and what you mean with lower impedance motors. A Nema17 is not a good motor?

Comment: Utter nonsense. They are one of the simpler dynamic circuits and you will encounter them so often that it is very useful to learn about them. And they are such a big topic that you will learn about details all the time. A perfect opportunity to learn

Comment: @PlasmaHH thanks for that comment ... glad you say this, otherwise I avoided them probably longer.

Comment: Yes - those are switching DC-DC converters - some of them over 90% efficient (compared to the 40%-ish efficiency you get from dropping 12V to 5V using a linear reg). You certainly won't need a heat sink (and I don't think any of them even have the option of adding one).

Comment: @brhans thanks ... really need to check between all possibilities. Maybe a stupid question, but are these buck converters?

Comment: To use a 12v supply with steppers, you typically want motors in the 4v range.  The chopping drive hits them with high voltage to overcome inductance, then chops back as the rated current is achieved.  The exception would be things that only need to move slowly, for example 3d printer X and Y get low voltage motors chopped from 12v, but Z can use a 12v coil (typically still run through a chopper, but one that doesn't really chop much).

Comment: @ChrisStratton What I actually want to make (eventually) is a moving light, which is like a 4x4x4" box, less than a kilo, to be moved in X and Y direction, reasonably fast. I saw examples on YouTube where Nema 17's are used, which seem to be 12 V.

Comment: you can also use a 7808 or an adjustable LDO to distribute the heat proportionally. you will want a heat sink with anything over even half a watt, less you get burned. the output of multiple linear regulators, if datasheet cap guidelines are followed, is silky smooth.

Comment: @dandavis That is what I intended with the 7809 and 7805, I assume with the 7808 it will be likewise. I have to check what an adjustable LDO is. With all other remarks I already know I need to learn much more about power supplies, but also it seems 12 V is not enough for what I need. But it's about the principle/learning more.

Comment: like the venerable lm317 or the slightly better [1117-ADJ](http://www.soloelectronica.net/PDF/LM1117.pdf) (multi-package, 1.2v dropout)

Comment: @dandavis I don't think I need an LDO version, but good to know the difference.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

A better solution is to put a resistor in series with the 7805.  The power dissipation will be shared between the regulator and the resistor.  This will reduce the peak power dissipation in the regulator.

The 7805 has a minimum input voltage of 7V.  If you need 200mA from a 12V source then you can use a resistor of...

(12V - 5V) / 200mA = 25 ohms.

The peak power dissipation in the regulator will occur when the voltage across the resistor is mid-way between 12V and 5V (which is 8.5V).  The current in the resistor will be (12V - 8.5V) / 25 ohms = 140mA at that point.

The power dissipation in the regulator will be 140mA * (8.5V - 5V) = 0.49W.

Thw peak power dissipation in the resistor occurs at max load (200mA).

The peak resistor power is 0.2A * 0.2A * 25 ohms = 1W.

Comment: Thanks, this is also a good idea. However, I don't have 1W resistors (but I can use two 0.5W resistors in series. Not sure if I have those  values though. 

Also, I think I can reduce the load by powering the LEDs from 12 V directly.

Comment: I calculated a bit (thanks to your equations), and I can use three 0.5W 10R resistors in series.

Comment: @MichelKeijzers Design this with care. If your +12V supply is unregulated, or has AC ripple, you must use its minimum voltage (which may be below +12V).

Comment: @glen_geek I'm intending to use a 12V adapter from a store, not to make it myself. According to Chris I might even need more than 12 V (but for the microprocessor board, I have to take safe values probably).